# How do I get an Alcatel X200 3g USB modem working?

Tags: 12.04, alcatel

I can't connect my Alcatel X200 in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin. I search some information, and i think is the kernel but i don't know how can i fix it.....

modeswitch work well because the "lsusb" return:

> Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1bbb:0000 T & A Mobile Phones

but when i try to add a new connection Ubuntu don't recognize it.

Can somebody help me??

---

Thank you very much! You has solved the problem that I have three years fixing. but, the connection is "invisible". Is like i'm disconnect, the icon of the connections is a triangle with the top line curve. Is ok? Can i do "visible" the connection?

I can't install nothing in the ubuntu software center, and Ubuntu One doesn't synchronize my files...

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

OK, try to avoid Network Manager, 
install and use `usb-modeswitch` with `wvdial` instead.

Edit `/etc/wvdial.conf` as follows:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
Baud = 460800
Modem Type = USB Modem
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Phone = *99#
Dial Command = ATDT
Username = INSERT DEFAULT USERNAME HERE (ask Your provider)
Password = INSERT DEFAULT PASSWORD HERE (might me the same, ask Your provider)
Stupid Mode = 1
Dial Attempts = 1
```

Open a terminal window or switch to another virtual console.

Run `sudo wvdial` to connect 
and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to close the connection.

If this fails you can try substituting other devices for the `Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1` line, such as:

```
/dev/ttyUSB2
/dev/ttyUSB3
...
```